# BizTalk CRM Dynamics 4 to Dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, upgrade, biztalk

My client is doing an upgrade from CRM Dynamics 4 to 2011 and it uses BizTalk 2009 as its ESB, they are currently using the 'Microsoft BizTalk Server Adapter for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0' for the Integration, my question is does anyone know what breaking changes are involved from a BizTalk point of view when this upgrade takes places?

Am I looking at a whole new set of contracts in CRM 11 e.g. WCF meaning code changes, mappings, schemas and moving away from the Adapter (4.) to pure WCF transport communication?

At this moment in time I'm trying to gauge the complexity and migration levels for one service...

Cheers

Comment: I haven't used the BizTalk adapter myself, so its difficult to comment. But assuming that it uses the CRM 4 web services, I would expect it to work, those web services are still valid on CRM 2011. However I suspect you will never really know until you try.

Comment: Thanks for the help James, it seems you are right too! I might assumption this out and then run a POC at build time...Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some first hand experience integrating BizTalk with CRM Online 2011.

The major difference is the change from the pre-defined CRM types, allowing compile-time type safety, to an un-typed Wcf interface.  A couple of (ugly) solutions to this problem have been documented around the web, but [this blog post](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/the-good-bad-and-ugly-of-integrating-dynamics-crm-2011-and-biztalk-server-2010/) by Richard Seroter defines a BizTalk-only solution.

We used a [third-party supplied adapter](http://www.roedl.com/services/consulting/integration/biztalk_adapter_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm_2011.html), developed by Roedl in Germany.  This uses the Wcf Adapter Framework, in a similar manner to the WCF-SQL adapter, to provide a set of compile-time strong-typed schemas.  This made it simple to map to and from the CRM types to our legacy system data types.

One disclaimer, we found that performance was "sufficient", without being outstanding.  If you need to move a **LOT** of data back and forth, consider using the bespoke solution, but if lower development cost is your prime motivation, it is worth considering.

Comment: Thanks Brett, I spoke to a local BizTalk Specialist today and he told me they have done this before and used Richards options B 'build proxy services for BizTalk to invoke that take in typed objects and communicate to Dynamics CRM", they created a proxy service between BizTalk and CRM 11 and then used the CRM 11 SDK (client side DLL's) to consume the native CRM Endpoints. Sounds messy but he said it was streets ahead of going with Richards option A in a real world environment (No offense to Richard ;)). Thanks for the link to the Adapter too, always worth a look at!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of this project as described will be huge especially considering the limitations of the BizTalk Server Adapter.  Have they considered using Scribe?  You might want to do a simple proof of concept project for them with the free evaluation version. [Scribe downloads](http://scribesoft.com/Downloads)

Comment: Thanks for your input mate, the scope is not huge, it's basically quantifying breaking changes as I don't think you can use the Adapter any more, WCF now. Re: Scribe, why would a company with an incumbent middleware product choose to change it's middleware during a dynamics upgrade, makes so sense!! ;)